# Why is this representation completely reducible?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

So I'm reading Georgi's Lie Algebras in Particle Physics. With $S$ be a **similarity transformation**: $D(g) \rightarrow D'(g) = S^{-1}D(g)S$, on page 6, he said:

> We will show later that any representation of a finite group is completely reducible.
>   For example, for $(1.5)$, take
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{1.15}
>     S
>   = \frac{1}{3}
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>         1
>       & 1
>       & 1
>       \\
>         1
>       & \omega^2
>       & \omega
>       \\
>         1
>       & \omega
>       & \omega^2
>     \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation}
>   where
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{1.16}
>   \omega = e^{2 \pi i /3}
> \end{equation}
>   then
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{1.17}
>     D'(e)
>   = \left(
>     \begin{smallmatrix}
>         1
>       & 0
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 1
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 0
>       & 1
>     \end{smallmatrix}
>     \right)
>   \quad
>     D'(a)
>   = \left(
>     \begin{smallmatrix}
>         1
>       & 0
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & \omega
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 0
>       & \omega^2
>     \end{smallmatrix}
>     \right)
>   \quad
>     D'(b)
>   = \left(
>     \begin{smallmatrix}
>         1
>       & 0
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & \omega2
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 0
>       & \omega
>     \end{smallmatrix}
>     \right).
> \end{equation}
>
> (Original scanned image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbMUw.jpg).)

Here's $(1.5)$:

> Here’s another representation of $Z_3$:
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{1.5}
>     D(e)
>   = \left(
>     \begin{smallmatrix}
>         1
>       & 0
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 1
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 0
>       & 1
>     \end{smallmatrix}
>     \right)
>   \quad
>     D(a)
>   = \left(
>     \begin{smallmatrix}
>         0
>       & 0
>       & 1
>       \\
>         1
>       & 0
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 1
>       & 0
>     \end{smallmatrix}
>     \right)
>   \quad
>     D'(b)
>   = \left(
>     \begin{smallmatrix}
>         0
>       & 1
>       & 0
>       \\
>         0
>       & 0
>       & 1
>       \\
>         1
>       & 0
>       & 0
>     \end{smallmatrix}
>     \right).
> \end{equation}
>
> (Original scanned image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAcvZ.jpg).)

I don't see how this $(1.17)$ can be **completely reducible**. Isn't it equivalent to the $Z_3$ representation in $(1.5)$ above, thus **irreducible** instead?

Thank you!

Edit: Answer: So since it's not clear $D(g)$ is irreducible or not, we use the **similarity transformation** $S$ to create **an equivalent representation** $D'(g)$. We see that $D'(g)$ is in block-diagonal form, and thus is obviously a completely reducible representation. Thus **both** $D(g)$ and $D'(g)$ are completely reducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The representation (1.5) is not irreducible.  The vector $e_1 + e_2 + e_3$ is an invariant vector with respect to the representation (1.5), so (1.5) is reducible.

The representation (1.17) is completely reducible, because all of the representing matrices for all the group elements are diagonal.  Thus $V = \langle e_1 \rangle \oplus \langle e_2 \rangle \oplus \langle e_3 \rangle$, and each element of this decomposition is invariant with respect to all group elements.

Comment: I'm dumb so I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the trivial representation? I fail to see how I can decompose $(1.5)$ into block diagonal form to prove that it's completely reducible...

Comment: (1.17) *is* the decomposition of (1.5) into block diagonal form.  When you apply a similarity transformation $S$, you change the basis (and hence the matrices) with respect to which the representation is expressed: $D'(g) = S^{-1} D(g) S$.  This transforms (1.5) into (1.17), and shows that (1.5) is completely reducible.